# Partition a List in Prolog

Tags: prolog

This is the predicate:

```
partList(Len,L,R):-
    length(L,LL),
    length(R,RR),
    RR is LL/Len,
    append(R,L).
```

The query shows:

```
42 ?- partList(2,[t,t,t,f,f,t,f,f],R).
R = [[], [], [], [t, t, t, f, f, t, f, f]] .
```

But I want to partition into

```
[[t,t],[t,f],[f,t],[f,f]].
```

How do I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: you need to specify further what you want. Your definition shows *all* possible partitions - including yours!

Comment: I figure it out! Thanks for you help!                                                               partList(Len,[],[]).
               partList(Len,L,[H|T]):-
            length(H,Len),append(H,LT,L),partList(Len,LT,T).

Answer (score 2):

The easy way is to look at the problem are repeatedly stripping off the 1st N items from the head of the list (until the list is exhausted).

```
partition( []      , []        ) .   % if the source list is exhausted, we're done.
partition( [X]     , [X]       ) .   % if the source list contains just one item, we're done.
partition( [X,Y|Z] , [[X,Y]|R] ) :-  % if the source list contains 2 or more items, we take the 1st two, and ...
  partition(Z,R)                     % - recursively partition the remainder.
  .                                  % Easy!.
```

To make it generic isn't much more complex.

First, we need a way to partition the list into a *prefix*, containing N items (or fewer if the list isn't sufficiently long) and a *suffix*, containing whatever's left (which might be nothing):

```
take_prefix( _ , []     , []    , []     ) .  % if the source list is empty, both prefix and suffix are empty, regardless of the value of N.
take_prefix( 0 , [X|Xs] , []    , [X|Xs] ) .  % if N is 0, The prefix is the empty list and the suffix is the source list.
take_prefix( N , [X|Xs] , [X|P] , S      ) :- % otherwise, add the head to the prefix,
  N > 0 ,                                     % - assuming N > 0
  N1 is N-1 ,                                 % - decrement N
  take_prefix(N1,Xs,P,S)                      % - and recurse down.
  .                                           % Easy!
```

This is the crux of the matter. Once you have that, it's just a matter of repeatedly (and recursively) applying it until you get to the empty list:

```
partition( _ , [] , []   ) .  % if the source list is empty, we're done.
partition( N , L , [P|R] ) :- % otherwise...
  take_prefix(N,L,P,S) ,      % - break it up into a prefix and a suffix,
  partition(N,S,R)            % - and recurse down on the suffix.
  .                           % Easy!
```